# How do I search for "string 1" with grep only in files that contain "string 2"?

Tags: grep

On occasion I need to search for a specific string within several files, but the results are only relevant if those files contain a second specific string, not necessarily on the same line as that first specific string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -ril 'string 1' * | xargs grep -rin 'string 2'`

The -l includes only file names rather than the matching lines themselves.  The xargs reads the files to search from the standard output of the first grep.